# Simple Java Neural Network

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I've written a toy neural network in Java. I ran it several million times with the same outputs with only the randomized weights changing from run to run. The average of all of the outputs is not 0.5, as I would have expected. The code is in [this Github Repository](https://github.com/jack-t/petulant-octo-bear/tree/7e587c090c5f3b89854a39ed787b839fe4163817).

The `Layer` class:

```
public class Layer extends AbstractLayer {

    private double[][] weights;

    public Layer(int neurons, int prevLayerNeurons) {
        super(neurons);
        weights = new double[neurons][prevLayerNeurons + 1];
        randomize(weights);
    }

    protected void randomize(double[][] x) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x[j].length; i++) {
                weights[j][i] = Math.random();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double[] compute(double inputs[]) {
        Preconditions.checkArgument(inputs.length == weights[0].length - 1, "incorrect number of inputs");
        double[] ret = new double[neurons];
        for (int i = 0; i < neurons; i++) {
            double acc = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++) {
                acc += inputs[j] * weights[i][j];
            }
            acc -= weights[i][weights[i].length - 1];
            acc = sigmoid(acc);
            ret[i] = acc;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private double sigmoid(double x) {
        return 1 / (1 + Math.exp(-x));
    }
}
```

And the `Network` class:

```
public class Network {

    private List<AbstractLayer> layers;

    public Network(int[] neuronCounts) {
        layers = new LinkedList<AbstractLayer>();
        layers.add(new InputLayer(neuronCounts[0]));
        for (int i = 1; i < neuronCounts.length; i++) {
            layers.add(new Layer(neuronCounts[i], neuronCounts[i - 1]));
        }
    }

    public boolean[] run(double[] inputs) {
        double[] tmps = inputs;
        for (int i = 0; i < layers.size(); i++) {
            tmps = layers.get(i).compute(tmps);
        }
        boolean[] rets = new boolean[tmps.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rets.length; i++) {
            rets[i] = tmps[i] > 0.5;
        }
        return rets;
    }

    public AbstractLayer getLayer(int i) {
        return layers.get(i);
    }

}
```

These are the most relevant classes, but there are several others in the repository.

As it stands now, the class `Bootstrap` will run a 3-layer network with a fixed arrangement and set of inputs.

I'd appreciate any comments on the structure of the program, and on the correctness (or incorrectness) of the output.

Comment: As I'm thinking through this again, I'm realizing that there's no particular reason the average should be 0.5. Why, then, is the average roughly 0.6? Is that a property of the network's configuration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Finding the average output

Let's figure out what your average output should be.  Your neural network has 3 inputs in the first layer, 2 nodes in the second layer, and one output.  Each weight is randomized to a value from `0..1`, so call it `0.5` on average.

The inputs you use in the program are: `1, 0, 1`.  On each layer, you also have a "bias" input of `-1`.  So with average weights of `0.5`, the the input layer will do the following:

```
inputs = 1, 0, 1, -1
output = sigmoid(1*0.5 + 0*0.5 + 1*0.5 - 1*0.5) = sigmoid(0.5) = 0.62
```

The second layer has two nodes, each with average input `0.62`.  It will do:

```
inputs = 0.62, 0.62, -1
output = sigmoid(0.62*0.5 + 0.62*0.5 - 1*0.5) = sigmoid(0.12) = 0.53
```

So your average output should be `0.53`.  I modified your program to sum the outputs and found that this was close (actual was `0.528`).  Now as for the percentage of time the output is above `0.5`, that depends on the distribution of the output, and I don't know that it is easy to compute by hand.  But your program shows through experimentation that the answer is roughly 60% of the time.

### Random weights

I think that your choice of random weights from the range `0..1` is the source of your confusion.  If you were to choose random weights in the range `-1..1` like this:

```
weights[j][i] = Math.random()*2 - 1.0;
```

then your output would be `0.5` on average and the percentage of outputs greater than `0.5` would be 50% (I modified your program to verify this).  Perhaps that is what you were expecting.

As far as your neural net code goes, it appears to be correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

1. The `randomize` method is an overridable method and you calling it from the constructor, which is quite dangerous in Java. Methods which you call from the constructor shouldn't be overridable, i.e.: `private` or `final` or `static`. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors).
2. The precondition in the compute method would throw an exception if the input is `null`, so you can add an additional guard for that:

   ```
   Preconditions.checkNotNull(inputs);
   ```
3. At `#Layer(neurons,prevLayerNeurons)`, you're creating arrays based on the passed arguments. Are sure that the passed arguments are valid as an array length? Why don't you protect it?

   ```
   Preconditions.checkArgument(neurons > 0);
   Preconditions.checkArgument(prevLayerNeurons > 0);
   ```